# Any InstallPad alternatives?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, software-rec

I'm about to install new bunch of software on a Windows XP Pro PC and found [InstallPad](http://www.installpad.com) as a potential method to do it all. However before using it I was wondering if there were any other similar apps that could be better or easier to use?

Requirements (should haves more than must haves):
- Free
- Easy to use and configure - preferably from point and click in a GUI instead of command line parameters or config files
- Robust - bug free or still in active/ongoing development
- Some level of support or active community for help or tips
- Pre-existing file lists that can be adapted for own use or used outright.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Anyone got any ideas? 
I found this via Life Hacker:
http://lifehacker.com/5388408/ninite-bulk+installs-great-free-windows-apps. 
But you can't configure the install destination, and the range of apps is limited to what they have chosen.

Any ideas please?

Comment: May be a bit late, but here are some other suggestions: http://serverfault.com/questions/58816/automatic-install-of-software-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 2):

See [Allmyapps](http://allmyapps.com/windows-xp/) :

> Allmyapps makes software installation
>   a breeze. No matter how many
>   applications you need, 1 click is all
>   you need to have all your favorite
>   applications installed on your PC.
>
> Allmyapps also keeps your applications
>   safe! Would you need to reinstall your
>   system, Allmyapps takes care of
>   reinstalling all your favorite
>   applications in the blink of an eye.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Appsnap](http://appsnap.genotrance.com/) in the past. The list of applications is quite good. Not as pretty as InstallPad.

Comment: Seems to be dead - [last update](http://code.google.com/p/appsnap/downloads/list) is from 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to have a look at [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/updatechecker/) update checker

Answer (score 0):

I quite like [Ninite](http://ninite.com/) recently... It doesn't do updating, but it does install applications quickly with just what is needed to get it working - no toolbars or additional extras.

You are limited to their list of software, however, it covers pretty much everything used on a daily basis.

Comment: -1 : If you look at my comment to my own Question you'll see that I actually identified this myself!

Comment: I just read the question... You could of actually written the name in comments instead of expect people to read a whole article.